# How do I redirect to another page in my custom app for Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a simple webapp that I am showing as an app in Teams. I have set it up in App Studio and everything works as I expect and it's all great. It is showing my web app and that is what I want.

For some cases, I need to redirect to a different web app on a different domain. When testing from Microsoft Teams in my browser, it works fine. But when I test from Microsoft Teams in the desktop app, then the screen just turns grey when the redirect was supposed to happen.

I already added the domains to this dialog in Manifest Editor.

[image: image from dialog in Teams manifest editor]

Because the screen just goes grey with no explanation, I am having a hard time troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Can you check this link pls https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/general/debug

Comment: Thanks. This link tells how to run my app locally while it is running from Teams. That is handy, but I doubt MY app will be able to tell why Teams stopped showing my app. The grey screen shown is one from Teams, not one from my app. Anyway, I will check.

Comment: @NielsBrinch Could you please take a look at [Redirect across domains in a Microsoft Teams tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/cross-domain)?

Comment: Yes, it says "Ensure that the URL is included in the validDomains list in your manifest.". And this is what I have done already. It works in the browser version of Teams but not the Desktop version.

Comment: @NielsBrinch I tried the steps mentioned in the document I shared in my previous comment and it works fine for me both on desktop and web. I am able to redirect to another page from my tab. Could you please check if the tab you want to redirect to, is iframable and that it meets all the [Requirements for tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-requirements)?

Comment: Ahaaaa ... no it does not meet the requirements for a tab. Thanks. That must be it.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT would you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NielsBrinch Could you please take a look at [Redirect across domains in a Microsoft Teams tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/cross-domain)? Also please make sure that the tab you want to redirect to, is iframable and that it meets all the [Requirements for tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-requirements).

Comment: The key solution here was that I did not realize the rules of "Requirements for tab" applies to any page that is being showed in the tab and not just the main app itself.